# How to write a simple server-push implementation in Python using django?

Tags: python, django, comet, server-push, long-polling

I would like to write a simple server-push implementation either using long pooling or comet that integrates into the server.
I don't want to use a networking framework like twisted because I want to learn how everything is done internally.
What exactly should I learn?
What specifications should I look at?
I prefer something that fits to apache so long pooling is better right?
Is there a way to implement such a thing without any external framework like [Stackless Python](http://stackless.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Using Django it is not possible, because django works behind standard http server. To push you need to write a server supporting large number of paralell connections. To start with, I recommend reading Orbited source code. Read both server (python) and client (javascript) code.

Comment: so creating something that uses only their messaging middleware and some sockets is not possible? I would really like to not depend on a special server for this but to relay on something that can run on any server as long as it can run python (so I can deploy on any possible setting)

Comment: I don't believe that this is entirely true. I could imagine that, behind (for example) gunicorn, it could be done.